# Enabling nested virtualisation for Android Studio on Linux platform

Tags: linux, android-studio, emulation, virtualization

I want to run emulator for Android Studio on a Linux platform. Upon contaction Google (since I'm using Google server) I was told this : "nested virtualisation is not enabled out of the box for Compute Engine instances. Therefore you need to enable it manually," and was given this link for further query "https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances". Can anyone help me with this  since I'm not getting the exact procedure to  run an emulator for Android Studio on a Linux platform hosted on a Google server.

Comment: The Android emulator is a type of nested virtualisation as you're running a virtual guest (Android device) inside a virtual guest (your compute instance). All you need to do is follow the procedure Google have sent you.

Comment: It's very difficult to install Linux (gui) based system on Google server as I tried myself and  had to give up after getting loads of errors (since a number of commands have to be run just for installing the gui interface). I had to switch back to Windows Server and run android studio there and at the time of debugging I create a signed apk and then transfer it to my phone and run it manually. That's a good option atleast for me other than setting up  a Linux gui server which is a big headache!